# why dispatch not return any value in react and redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to create login using React and redux, login api working fine and return success, but the dispatch not returing any thing, it shows some error, look out the below codes

Login.js

```
const handleLogin=(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();

  setLoading(true);     
  dispatch(login(userName, password))
    .then((response)=>{          
      console.log(response)
      props.history.push("/masters/dealerMaster");
      window.location.reload();
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log('h', error);
      setLoading(false);
    })
};
```

Action.js

```
import { 
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT,
    SET_MESSAGE
 } from './types';

 import AuthService from '../services/auth.services';

 export const login  = (userName, password)=>(dispatch)  =>{
     return AuthService.login(userName, password).then(
         (data)=>{
             dispatch({
                 type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                 payload : {user : data},
             });

             return Promise.resolve();
         },
         (error)=>{
             const message = (
                error.message && 
                error.response.data &&
                error.response.data.message) || 
                error.message ||
                error.toString();
                
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAIL
                });

                dispatch({
                    type: SET_MESSAGE,
                    payload : message
                });

                return Promise.reject();
            }
     );
 };

 export const logout=()=> (dispatch)=>{
    AuthService.logout();
    dispatch({
        type : LOGOUT
    });
 }
```

Reducer > auth.js

```
import {
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from '../actions/types';

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

const initalState = user 
    ? {isLoggedIn: true, user}
    : {isLoggedIn: false, user : null};

export default function(state = initalState, action){
    const {type, payload} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn : true,
                user : payload.user
            };
        case LOGIN_FAIL : 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn : false,
                user : null
            }
        case LOGOUT : 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn : false,
                user : null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Below are the errors i've received.
If we refresh the page it will redirect the next page.
what is the major issue i made

[image]

Please help me out im new to React and Redux.

Comment: Can you include the SIgnIn component's code?

Comment: its probably because when you unmount Singin component (redirect to new page) there is some promise data back to Signin and try to re-render the component which doesnt exist anymore. like Mosh said post your Signin component code please.

Comment: or try setTimeout(()=>{props.history.push("/masters/dealerMaster");
      window.location.reload();}, 10000)

Comment: @MoshFeu please check my signIn component code from here 
https://jsfiddle.net/sathishcst10/drjh9kLa/1/

Comment: if(isLoggedIn){
      return _navigateTo("/masters/dealerMaster");
    } 
is not right mate. when LoggedIn is true your component will not render anything it is not allowed in react